# Book Series, England, Goddesses, Reincarnation

Tags: story-identification, mythology

I'm trying to recall the author/book series based on goddesses and mythology, set in England; in multiple books the series moves to war time England, with the fight between two women (goddesses) and the man they love continues.  Reincarnation?  There's a very intricate dance, and a labyrinth is also an integral part of the story.

Comment: Do you recall what kind of war time? Ancient or modern?

Comment: the series initially started in pre-medieval England.  Over the course of the books it became more modern and I want to say the last book I read had them in England during WWI?  there was a strong greek/mythology feel to it; a big connection with the goddesses and water; as well as Stonehenge mentioned.  They were building a city on a hilltop if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the [Troy Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Troy_Game) series by [Sara Douglass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sara_Douglass). From Wikipedia:

> The Troy Game is a quartet by Australian author [Sara Douglass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sara_Douglass) consisting of four books: Hades' Daughter, God's Concubine, Darkwitch Rising and Druid's Sword. It centres around a group of characters who are reincarnated at the end of each book and take the form of renowned historical figures from different ages. The entire series is set in London and focuses on the characters trying to complete the Troy Game, a kind of spell cast in the first book to protect the city.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that is the series. Much appreciated! I was hoping for a 5th book :)

Comment: @Lisa if this is the correct answer, don't forget to accept it